# GSAP animation working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm working on an animation using some GSAP code an a bit of custom JS I tweaked from another project.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMVGov

```
function startAnimation() {

    var line1 = document.getElementById("line1");
    var line2 = document.getElementById("line2");
    var line3 = document.getElementById("line3");   
    var tl = new TimelineMax(); 

    //main timeline .. set lines to off and back on at the correct time tl

    tl
    .set(line1, {opacity: 0}, "0")
    .set(line2, {opacity: 0}, "0")
    .set(line3, {opacity: 0}, "0")
    .set(line1, {opacity: 1}, "0")
    .set(line2, {opacity: 1}, "3")
    .set(line3, {opacity: 1}, "6");

    //Drawlines Animation takes element
    function drawLinesTween(line, startTime) {
        var pathToDraw = line, length, timer;
        var obj = {length:0, pathLength:pathToDraw.getTotalLength()};
        pathToDraw.style.stroke = '#f1562b';
        var t = TweenMax.to(obj, 3, {length:obj.pathLength, onUpdate:drawLine, ease:Linear.easeNone, opacity: 100, delay: startTime});
        function drawLine() {
            pathToDraw.style.strokeDasharray = [obj.length, obj.pathLength].join(' ');
        }
    }

    drawLinesTween(line1, "0");
    drawLinesTween(line2, "3");
    drawLinesTween(line3, "6");

}
startAnimation();
```

The custom code is causing the issue. It works fine on Chrome but not in Firefox where on Windows it is throwing a type error in the console and on OS nothing.

The jagged line is meant to be drawn out in an animated fashion in orange.

Anyone have any ideas where the code is wrong here?

Comment: In your code example, and on your CodePen, the variable `startTime` is missing, could you update it with the desired value?

Comment: Made a change to that now. Is it correct with regards to the var now? Or do I need to declare it inside the function?

Comment: No it's okay, problem is that the method `getTotalLength` is not available for all browsers, and all elements.
Only path element (but still no support on Safari for instance).
[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength)

Comment: You can try to use this method in this post, if you can't use `path` instead of `polyline`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890748/how-can-i-get-length-of-svg-polyline-element

Comment: Got that working! you can check the codepen as I've updated it. Now to test across some browsers before I implement it in production!