# Line Animation while using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

My client is asking for lines that connect text (basic p tags) with buttons from an image (please see attached photo), I am having a hard time finding out how to accomplish this and make sure it's responsive.

[image: End Result]

I had two ideas on how to accomplish this:

Import the line image (the client gave me a png file) and use CSS to make the line fit correctly on the image. The problem with that is it loses the correct placement once I size down the screen. I have my code here on codepen, I have everything working from the image above except those dang lines: 
https://codepen.io/dec23rd1986/full/PdEoZa/

I also thought about SVG animation but I'm not sure how I would incorporate that with the jQuery I'm using for my buttons. Which I'm using to go back and forth between the two buttons and the side arrow buttons, along with the fade effect.

If anyone can point in me the right direction on how to accomplish this (articles, videos, best approach) I would greatly appreciate it!
Best Regards,

```
   <div class="container-fluid jumbo_features">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ijvTfU/feature_meeting.png" class="meeting_img">

      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hZNxPp/feature_tasks.png" class="tasks_img"></div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
      <button type="button"  class="btn active" aria-pressed="true" id="meeting_button">Meeting</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn" aria-pressed="true" id="tasks_button">Tasks</button>

       <br>
     <p class="meeting_info"><b>Attends Meetings:</b><br>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p><br>
     <p class="meeting_info "><b>Takes meeting notes:</b><br>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
      <!--Tasks-->
       <p class="tasks_info"><b>Example One</b><br>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p><br>
              <p class="tasks_info"><b>Example Two</b><br>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p><br>
              <p class="tasks_info"><b>Example Three</b><br>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p><br>

         </div>
          </div>
       </div>

      <br>
       </div>
      </div>  
    </div>

</div>
</div>
       <div class ="meeting_info">
<img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/c4yUFU/line1.png" id="line">
```

Comment: I'd use SVG, personally. Have you tried using it? You can get your lines to scale by using percentages for all the values rather than pixel positions.

Comment: Hi Bob! I've been looking into SVG recently but have never used it. Would you recommend that I create the lines via SVG or use an image that is saved as a SVG file and then use CSS to style it? I tested this over in my codepen but was having trouble on how I would incorporate it using my jQuery. Can you let me know what this feature in SVG would be called?

Comment: I'd just make lines. I'll put an example in an answer. You can also play with [this](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_line.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not clear on precisely why your jQuery might interfere with your use of lines, here's a simple SVG example which will scale as you change the window size. All you have to do to make it scale is use percentage values rather than literal pixel values.

If you have some proportional changes as screen sizes change, then you might have to alter this code programmatically. If you provide more information on why you have concerns about interacting with jQuery, please share them and I'll update my answer.

**Edit:** I've updated my example to give a rough idea (for example, the message doesn't always line up properly) of what I think you're looking for. If I understand you right, you can refine it from there. Also, you may wish to change your percentages with screens of different sizes. If so, use `@media` queries in your CSS.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 32%;
}

#myImg img {
  width: 100%;
}

#mySVG {
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: -10%;
}

#myMsg {
  margin-top: 28.5%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myImg">
  <img src="https://www.yotako.io/images/documentation/balsamiq/containers/android_balsamiq.png" />
</div>
<div id="mySVG">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="0" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:2" />
  <line x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="50%" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:2" />
  <line x1="50%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="myMsg">
  <p>Your message goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Bob. Question, how would I make this SVG align perfectly with the left images buttons? Would that be a matter of fixing the margins in CSS?

Comment: @Alexandra Yes and no. I would put the SVG in a div, and use CSS to size and align the div (yes, probably with margins rather than padding, as you appear to want the lines to overlap the image to some extent) as you want it in relation to your graphic phone image.

Comment: @Alexandra I've added a rough example in my answer.

Comment: it looks great! I will be sure to try and implement this! Thanks so much for your insight. I went from not knowing how to approach this to understanding more about SVG!

Comment: @Alexandra You're very welcome. Hope it all works out for you.

Comment: Hi Bob, I was able to add my SVG line along with my working jQuery, however I don't think I'll be able to align my lines perfectly with my images because my images/text are in a bootstrap container. So they container is constantly sizing down when needed. I liked your example, but I'm not sure how to implement that with my bootstrap container. I'm using (2) columns. Here is my working codepen: https://codepen.io/dec23rd1986/full/PdEoZa/

Comment: @Alexandra Ok, I've had a quick look. I don't know bootstrap, but why don't you have the SVG in the bootstrap container as well? (I take it that's the main div with the `container-fluid` class.) In other words, why don't you take the `div` layout I have here and enclose the entire thing in the bootstrap container?

Comment: Hi Bob, I incorporated your code inside my container div and when I tried to sized down the screen, it responded jsut as I thought, the SVG line was sizing down incorrectly (under the phone). I believe this is because of bootstrap. I might just have to do this feature your way, without bootstrap incorporated since it's making it very difficult to accomplish. It seems that is the easiest when trying to make it responsive.

Comment: @Alexandra Yes, you are. :) You have three lines, each defined by two endpoints, which endpoints are defined as `x,y`. The first line begins at `0,0` and ends at `50%,0`. Meaning, it starts in the top left hand corner of the available area, and extends along the top to the vertical centerline. (Negative numbers don't work because `0,0` is the top left corner.) So, if you want the "middle line to go up," you need to make the first line's `y` values higher than the second line's. To make the exact reverse of my example, just transpose the `x,y` values of the two horizontal lines.

Comment: @Alexandra [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_line) is a place you can play with different values and see their results. The site also has pretty much everything you need to know about SVG, should you be interested in experimenting further.

Comment: @Alexandra [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_line) is a place you can play with different values and see their results. The site also has pretty much everything you need to know about SVG, should you be interested in experimenting further. p.s. You're not bothering me. I've spent most of my career teaching. :)

Comment: Thanks so much @BobRodes! Best Regards, Andrea

Comment: FWIW, gazdagergo's `polyline` tag is a more concise solution.

Answer (score 2):

For the **line animation** part, you do not need to use anything else but svg's own animation feature:

```html
<svg height="120" width="120">
  <polyLine
    id="myLine"
    points="120,0 60,0 60,60 0,60"
    fill="none"
    stroke-width="2"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-dasharray="240"
    stroke-dashoffset="240"
  />

  <animate
    xlink:href="#myLine"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    from="240"
    to="0"
    dur="3s"
    begin="1s"
    fill="freeze"
   />   
</svg>
```

*PS: you can get the total length (`240`) [with calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890748/how-can-i-get-length-of-svg-polyline-element), but for a limited number of lines it is ok to manually calc it.*

Comment: Thanks man! The animation part is an important feature for my client. I'll def check this out.

Comment: `points` represents the coordinates in `x1,y1 x2,y2 x3,y3 ...` format. I changed the points in the example.